# How to enable Nvidia encoder and why I got error on Nvidia Driver after Uninstall Cuda

Tags: drivers, nvidia

my os is Ubuntu 18.04.

I want to enable NVENC encoder for OBS recording. I followed this tutorial: https://scottlinux.com/2016/09/12/how-to-enable-nvidia-nvenc-for-obs-in-linux/

But on step 2, I made a mistake. I installed Cuda from ubuntu repository, not just copy Cuda.h.

And after I installed Cuda from repository (apt get cuda). I rebooted my laptop, and then I couldn't start the GUI. 
I can start the GUI again after to uninstall Cuda, but I also lost my nvidia driver when uninstalling cuda.

Then, I tried reinstall the nvidia driver base on this guide: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-nvidia-driver-latest-proprietary-driver/
My vga is Nvidia 930MX and I installed nvidia-driver-435.

Nothing error when installing the driver. But when I reboot my laptop, I could't start GUI again. I tried to another version nvidia-driver-390, nvidia-driver-430. But nothing works.

Now, I decided to use Intel HD for emergency purpose. But on startup (dmesg log), I got this error:

```
[  281.674620] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.5
[  281.674640] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
[  281.674655] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[  281.674667] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER:    [12] Timeout               
[  307.377696] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.5
[  307.377708] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
[  307.377718] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[  307.377726] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER:    [12] Timeout               
[  424.630009] systemd-journald[356]: File /var/log/journal/db71aa7f5c2f459083471d2a40ef5a91/user-1000.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
[  425.928959] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  425.928968] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  425.928978] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  427.172678] rfkill: input handler disabled
[  493.668193] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.5
[  493.668210] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
[  493.668213] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00003000/00002000
[  493.668214] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER:    [12] Timeout               
[  501.530352] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.5
[  501.530358] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
[  501.530360] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[  501.530362] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER:    [12] Timeout               
[  502.306367] userif-4: sent link down event.
[  502.306369] userif-4: sent link up event.
[  701.431701] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.5
[  701.431721] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
[  701.431738] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[  701.431749] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER:    [12] Timeout               
[  771.912488] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.5
[  771.912509] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
[  771.912522] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[  771.912531] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER:    [12] Timeout
```

I want get back my nvidia driver. Anyone can solved this proble or given a suggested solution.

**UPDATE 1: Now I solved nvidia driver error problem with following step.**

1. Remove all nvidia package and reboot

```
sudo apt purge nvidia-driver-440
sudo apt autoremove
```

2. Install nvidia driver from run binary, that's available on [nvidia website.](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx). If there are dkms error, run:

```
sudo apt install dkms
```

If there are error unable to load the 'nvidia-drm' kernel module. Remove xorg.conf

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Then install the binary nvida driver.

> I am waiting your help to find a best way to enable nvenc encoder on OBS.

Comment: You might be better to follow this for nvenc: https://askubuntu.com/a/837320/57576

Comment: I've tried it, but not works