# The minimum required Nvidia driver for nvenc is 435.21 or newer?

Tags: upgrade

I've just upgraded Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. Unfortunately, some things such as OBS component has been broken.

Here are some of the log captured in `/var/log/syslog`

```
Aug 23 10:13:38 pc com.obsproject.Studio.desktop[5817]: [h264_nvenc @ 0x55a8e843d200] Driver does not support the required nvenc API version. Required: 9.1 Found: 8.1

Aug 23 10:13:38 pc com.obsproject.Studio.desktop[5817]: [h264_nvenc @ 0x55a8e843d200] The minimum required Nvidia driver for nvenc is 435.21 or newer

Aug 23 10:13:38 pc com.obsproject.Studio.desktop[5817]: warning: [NVENC encoder: 'simple_h264_recording'] Failed to open NVENC codec: Function not implemented
```

I've updated the system with `sudo apt update -y && sudo apt upgrade -y` but did not fix the problem.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: I think it's ffmpeg requirenment

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get remove '^nvidia'
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-435 # or alternatively nvidia-driver-440
sudo reboot
```

If after these coimmands you still get a `Failed to open NVENC codec: Function not implemented` error message see
[How to install / compile NVENC in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/778100/).