# Using Kubuntu to accelerate FFmpeg using Nvidia GPU

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, ffmpeg, gpu

I’ve installed Kubuntu so that I can run FFmpeg to join a large number of tiff files into a video.  The tiffs are produced by a video enhance program that exports each frame of the video as a tiff.

I’ve installed FFmpeg from the console.  I’m following the instructions found here:
https://docs.nvidia.com/video-technologies/video-codec-sdk/ffmpeg-with-nvidia-gpu/#compiling-ffmpeg

The instructions are failing at this line:

cd nv-codec-headers && sudo make install && cd –

with an error ‘no such directory cd – ‘

I think that this could be due to my not starting in the correct directory, and therefore the command hasn’t got a directory to ‘go back to’.  I am very new to this and I could be completely wrong!  I do know that I am in ‘nv-codec-headers’ directory after the command has run, which matches the ‘cd’ at the start of the line.

If I carry on the command

./configure --enable-nonfree -–enable-cuda-sdk –enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64

also fails, but I don’t know whether this is due to the above failing.  It’s the ./configure part that is causing the problem.

Can anyone help with this, please?

Comment: `cd` means change directory. It can only be followed by a path.  This is why you are getting that error. Your instructions are incorrect.  It's hard to advise any further because you didn't link to the directions and you also did not use any formatting in your post, so the commands that you typed are not possible for us to parse. Please edit your question and include the link to the directions you are following. You should also use the formatting tools so that we can parse these commands. Use `monospace` font for anything going into or from the terminal and retain all line breaks.

Comment: Do you simply want to use FFmpeg with h264_nvenc for your encoding?

Comment: Yes, I simply want to speed up FFmpeg when it joins the Tiffs into a video.

Comment: I've got round the cd problem but ./configure fails with  -–enable-cuda-sdk  bad option.

Comment: @derekc23 You might be just as well to follow the nvenc guide on AskUbuntu https://askubuntu.com/q/778100/57576 and then follow the full FFmpeg trac guide: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed one thing. If you copied the command from Nvidias homepage, it fails.
For some reason, the "-" in the command is not the character you expect. Type them manually instead.